# Run time error occurs only for some users

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a DB that I send to various users in my company. They have mostly standardized work environments which match my own, but there are exceptions.

The code provided below, which is called using the AutoExec Macro, works flawlessly on my own machine.However, for some users it generates this error message:

> run time error 3027: Cannot update. Database or object is read only.

The line the debugger goes to is...

```
CurrentDb.Properties("StartUpShowDBWindow") = False 'Turn OFF Navigation pane
```

**Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?**

I am at a loss on how to proceed or solve this error as I can't reproduce it. Thus my question to all of you.

Here my code:

```
Public Function StartUpDB()

'Disable regular close button
Call AccessCloseButtonEnabled(False)

'Set Variable used in rest of script
sUSER = modGLOBAL.fncUserName

'Enable or disable the Admin tab
If IsAdmin = True Then
'   ADMIN SETUP STARTS HERE
   CurrentDb.Properties("StartUpShowDBWindow") = True 'Turn ON Navigation pane
   CurrentDb.Properties("AllowFullMenus") = True 'Turn ON full menu
Else
'   BU SETUP STARTS HERE
'   CurrentDb.Properties("StartUpShowDBWindow") = False 'Turn OFF Navigation pane
'   CurrentDb.Properties("AllowFullMenus") = False 'Turn OFF full menu
End If

DoCmd.OpenForm "Hidden", acNormal, , , , acHidden 'Start hidden form with timer

End Function
```

Comment: First of all check if user has read-write rights on accdb file.

Comment: I assume you mean the actual file itself. I created a User rights system within the DB itself, but this isn't causing the problem. Is this something I can do in the code?

Comment: I was just going through some old notes and found this: `"If a startup property hasn't been set previously, you must create it and add it to the *Properties* collection of the *Database* object."`. hth.

Comment: Are you able to modify other objects or local tables on PC with issue?

Comment: @SergeyS. I have gotten the DB in question to run by simply commenting out the offending lines. The DB does everything else it's supposed to do, including running other code, adding records, and switching on and off other controls in a form.

Comment: @Waze I know I can add properties to a DB, but is this possibly one that already exists, and is simply hidden (like AllowBypassKey)?

Comment: I mean, for instance try to edit manually the form in designer and save changes. In read-only database possible to change data in linked tables (not local), hide, show and move controls using VBA etc. Sometimes the file just has read-only attribute, which causes similar problems.

Comment: Does it always occur for these users, or only sometimes? If someone else has an exclusive lock on the database object (e.g. someone has a form open in design view or someone is editing a VBA module) this can occur.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth It always happens. So it is not related to "shared" or "exclusive" access problems like I just described in my answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834620/you-do-not-have-access-to-the-database-this-time-if-you-proceed-to-make-changes/44517262#44517262.

Comment: changing properties at run-time don't take affect until you restart the application. it sounds like your intent is to secure the app, before sharing it, so you need to set those properties, and then share your app. users don't need to rerun those, it kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb223465(v=office.12).aspx) as some things you can look into. I dont think it's anything you can fix with code, unless it has something to do with code on the form you are opening.

Comment: `CurrentDb.Properties("StartUpShowDBWindow") = False` may be valid syntax for some versions of Access but not others (older versions). Check Access version for those that fail and see if this syntax works there. If not find another way to accomplish task and place an `If` block to test for version.

Comment: 1) check office version and run windows update, some update could break working access.
2) run decompile, C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE  c:\mydb.accdb /decompile (save my life many times when strange errors come)